# How to connect 2013 Macbook to external Monitor?

Tags: mac, hdmi, vga, dvi

It looks like they dropped mini displayport for hdmi but I unfortunately have a monitor that only accepts VGA or DVI.  Can I output to VGA or DVI via USB or thunderbolt?

http://support.apple.com/kb/SP669

[http://www.amazon.com/Acer-G276HL-1080p-Backlit-Monitor/dp/B0098Y77N2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0098Y77N2)

Comment: I'm thinking of this, but would love confirmation. I know simple adapters from HDMI to vga don't really exist. http://www.amazon.com/EnjoyGadgets-Thunderbolt-video-adapter-cable/dp/B006GG1Q7I/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1391472942&sr=1-1&keywords=thunderbolt+to+vga

Comment: Thunderbolt is MiniDP (with added features). So any MiniDP adapter should work fine.  I have the Apple one for uDP->VGA and uDP->DVI, both work well.  I've heard of issues of other brands' adapters for some but not all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple page you link to tells you under Thunderbolt digital video output

> DVI output using Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter (sold separately)
>   VGA output using Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter (sold separately)

You need a Mini DisplayPort to to X adapter Both are listed as BTO options on the Mac or elsewhere in the Apple Store

Mini Display port and Thunderbolt sockets look the same so yo plug a Mini Displayport end of a lead into the Thunderbolt socket

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I have a 2013 MacBook Pro and use the Thunderbolt port as a Mini DisplayPort also. Here are two cables that can solve your problem by connecting from Mini DisplayPort to VGA and DVI, respectively. (I linked to the 6' versions however monoprice.com has them in other lengths as well.)

http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024605&p_id=6003

http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024604&p_id=5999

(Just a happy monoprice customer. If you live outside the USA there are likely local options.)